# How to show contents from other Models in my view using .NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, frontend

I have an `Index` view that should display the name of each person's course, however, in the model used there is only the `Course Id`, the course name is in another model - `CursosModel` - and in another table in the database. How can I display the course name in my view?

Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<FeedbackUnivicosa.Models.Professor>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Professores";
}

<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="SearchString" class="inputSearch" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
            <button type="submit" class="botaoSearch fa fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></button>
            <a asp-action="Index"><i class="espacoFiltro fa fa-solid fa-filter-circle-xmark"></i></a>
            <a asp-action="Create" class="botaoCadastro btn btn-primary btn-sm">Cadastrar</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">Professor</a> 
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["EmailSortParm"]">Email</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CursoSortParm"]">Curso</a>
            </th>
           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td class="fa-lg">
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="espacoIcone fa-solid fa-user-pen"></i></a>
                    
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="espacoIcone fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></a>       
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailProfessor)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CursoId)
            </td>
           
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to show the course name on the `Index` view.

Comment: Add the following DB Model class to the Models folder
reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description of this question, I think you can inject your DBContext into your view and get the value of `course name` from `CursosModel` table, Please refer to this simple demo:

Model:

```
public class CursosModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string CursoName { get; set; }
    }

public class Professor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the view, You can inject dbcontext into your view then get the `course Name` by  Professor's CourseId.

```
@using xxxx;
@model IEnumerable<Professor>
@inject ApplicationDbContext dbcontext

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="fa-lg">
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="espacoIcone fa-solid fa-user-pen"></i></a>

            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="espacoIcone fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseId)
        </td>
        <td>
           @dbcontext.cursosModels.Where(x => x.id == item.CourseId).Select(y => y.CursoName).FirstOrDefault();       
        </td>
        <br>
    </tr>
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

because the Microsoft website teaches Add the model
so after you can reference the Microsoft site.

[reference Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
public class CursosModel
    {
        public List<CursosModel> CursosModel { get; set; }
        public List<Course> Course{ get; set; }
    }
```